# Diastole/systole pressure in transcapillary circulation

Tags: blood-circulation, circulatory-system

The Starling equation factors in hydrostatic pressure and oncotic pressure. Given that the hydrostatic pressure in capillaries is pulsed, alternating between systole and diastole, does reabsorption tend to be favoured in diastole (low hydrostatic pressure, low volume from filtration in systole and therefore high concentration of colloids i.e. high osmotic pressure)?